# Rust idiomatic way of polymorphic struct

Tags: rust, polymorphism

I've implemented a simple polymorphic structure, which looks a bit ugly and I'm afraid I am missing an idiomatic way of doing it.

To describe briefly what I'm trying to achieve here: I would like to have a structure with a collection of handlers, which all must implement specific trait.

```
use std::fmt;
use std::fmt::Formatter;
use std::fmt::Error;

trait Handler {
    fn get_type(&self) -> String;
}

struct FileHandler {
}

struct DbHandler {
}

impl Handler for FileHandler {
    fn get_type(&self) -> String {
        "file".to_string()
    }
}

impl Handler for DbHandler {
    fn get_type(&self) -> String {
        "db".to_string()
    }
}

struct Config {
    handlers: Vec<Box<Handler>>
}

impl fmt::Debug for Config {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error> {
        for h in self.handlers.iter() {
            println!("{}", h.get_type());
        }
        write!(f, "config")
    }
}

pub fn run() {
    let mut handlers: Vec<Box<Handler>> = Vec::new();

    let fh = FileHandler {};
    let dh = DbHandler {};

    handlers.push(Box::new(fh));
    handlers.push(Box::new(dh));

    let c = Config { handlers };
    println!("{:?}", c);
}
```

Is there a way of more cleaner or more idiomatic solution here?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "looks a bit ugly"? Ugliness is not a universally shared concept.

Comment: @Shepmaster It's ugly for me as a newcomer to rust, practically, not in a way that rust is ugly, but how I've done it =) But I can't really say how it should look in a better implementation. I guess by "ugly" I mean I'm not quite sure it's idiomatic enough.

Comment: Just a little question: why is `Config` generic?

Comment: @Boiethios whoops, got there by accident, from my previous tries of implementation. Removed it as redundant, thanks for the notice

Comment: Not a full answer to the question, but [a couple of stylistic tweaks you might like](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=81c09e0cb83af3860a4fcd7e291dea18&version=stable) - you can replace the `self.handlers.iter()` in your `for` loop with `&self.handlers` (as `&Vec<T>` implements `IntoIterator<&T>`) , and you can drop the braces from structs with no fields.

Comment: You probably meant to use `writeln!(f, ...)?;` in your `Debug` impl instead of `println!(...);`.

Comment: @FrancisGagné thanks, that's true, was printing just to see if I'm getting the values properly